# Error pasting a worksheet from one excel workbook to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

From a VBA project in Excel, I want to open another workbook, copy the contents of a worksheet and paste it into a worksheet where my project is running.  I am basically trying to create a restore feature.

I created the following macro to do the job which worked.

```
Sub CopyandPaste()
'
' CopyandPaste Macro
'

'
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\ Backup-File.xlsm"
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Current_File.xlsm").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

I then added the code to my VBA project.  I am getting a **“Run-time error 1004 – PasteSpecial method of class failed”** on the line:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

If I use “ActiveSheet.Paste”, the data is pasted in to the Current_File.xlsm but my formulas are lost.

Can anyone help.  I have scoured this and other forums and cannot find where I am going wrong. I suspect I am close to the solution but nothing is working.

Goeff

Comment: Is any of the sheet protected or have merged cells ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
Sub CopyandPaste()
'
' CopyandPaste Macro
'
Dim rng As Range
'
     Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\ Backup-File.xlsm"
   ' Cells.Select
  ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    Windows("Current_File.xlsm").Activate
    'Cells.Select
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go as follows

```
Sub CopyandPaste()
    Windows("Current_File.xlsm").ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Clear ' clear previous content in "active sheet of "Current_File"

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= "C:\Backup-File.xlsm"
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy destination:=Windows("Current_File.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Range("A1") ' copy "Backup-File" "active" sheet used range and paste them to "Current_File" "active" sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: @Goeff, any feedback?